# Controlar tamaño de campo SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo un campo en mi tabla declarado **Numeric (18,2)**, pero al insertar desde una aplicación **Asp** el dato se inserta ejemplo "1.5" cuando se inserta desde el ASP queda en SQL "1.5000", Revisamos y es configuración regional, pero no se puede modificar por otra aplicación que también corre desde el mismo server.
Desde mi SP

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SPUPDATEANALISIS
    --PARAMETROS
     @CODIGOANALISIS INT
    ,@PROTEINA NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@HUMEDAD NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@HUMEDADTB NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@GRASA NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@CENIZA NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@DIGESTIBILIDAD NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@ACIDEZ NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@ACIDEZMASTERFOODS NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@PEROXIDO NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@T10 NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@T12 NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@T18 NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@CALCIO NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@CODIGOLOTE INT
    ,@CODIGOESTADO INT
    ,@COMENTARIO VARCHAR(500)
    ,@ORGANOLEPTICO VARCHAR (50)
    ,@FOSFORO NUMERIC (18,2)
    ,@CODIGOUSUARIO INT
    --,@FECHAREGISTRO DATETIME
    ,@CODIGOSUBESTADO INT
    ,@CODIGOCLIENTESUBESTADO INT
    ,@OBSERVACIONSUBESTADO VARCHAR (200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESPUESTA VARCHAR (100)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblResultadoAnalisis WHERE codigoAnalisis = @CODIGOANALISIS)
            BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                    BEGIN TRAN Tupd
                        BEGIN TRY
                            UPDATE tblResultadoAnalisis 
                                SET
                                PROTEINA = @PROTEINA, 
                                HUMEDAD = @HUMEDAD,
                                HUMEDADTB = @HUMEDADTB, 
                                GRASA = @GRASA, 
                                CENIZA = @CENIZA, 
                                DIGESTIBILIDAD = @DIGESTIBILIDAD, 
                                ACIDEZ = @ACIDEZ, 
                                ACIDEZMASTERFOODS = @ACIDEZMASTERFOODS, 
                                PEROXIDO = @PEROXIDO,
                                T10 = @T10, 
                                T12 = @T12, 
                                T18 = @T18,  
                                CALCIO = @CALCIO, 
                                CODIGOESTADO = @CODIGOESTADO, 
                                COMENTARIO = @COMENTARIO, 
                                ORGANOLEPTICO = @ORGANOLEPTICO, 
                                FOSFORO = @FOSFORO,
                                CODIGOUSUARIO = @CODIGOUSUARIO,
                                FECHAREGISTRO = GETDATE(),
                                CODIGOSUBESTADO = @CODIGOSUBESTADO,
                                CODIGOCLIENTESUBESTADO = @CODIGOCLIENTESUBESTADO,
                                OBSERVACIONSUBESTADO = @OBSERVACIONSUBESTADO
                                WHERE codigoAnalisis = @CODIGOANALISIS
                                    SET @RESPUESTA = @HUMEDAD --AQUI VIENE EL CAMPO PARA SABER COMO BAJO DESDE ASP
                                    SELECT @RESPUESTA AS RESPUESTA -- LO IMPRIMIMOS PARA VER COMO BAJO EL DATO
                                COMMIT TRAN Tupd
                        END TRY
                    BEGIN CATCH
                        SET @RESPUESTA = 'NO INSERTE'
                    ROLLBACK TRAN Tupd
                    SELECT @RESPUESTA AS RESPUESTA
                    END CATCH
            END
END
```

Como puedo obligar a que ese campo quede (1.5) y no con tantos decimales.

Gracias por sus aportes

Comment: Sería interesante probablemente ver el código que llama a este procedimiento almacenado.

Answer (score 1):

Esto que planteas se relaciona con

[Precisión, escala y longitud (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> La precisión es el número de dígitos de un número. La escala es el número de dígitos situados a la derecha de la coma decimal de un número. Por ejemplo, el número 123,45 tiene una precisión de 5 y una escala de 2.

Entonces en tu caso deberias definir un `decimal(2,1)`

El 2 indicaria el numero de digitos y el 1 la cantidad de digitos a la derecha de la coma decimal

Answer (score 0):

En tu procedimiento almacenado puedes aplicar el formato del valor.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1.5000, 'N1')
```

Resultado:

```
1.5
```

Fuente: [How to Format Numbers in SQL Server](https://database.guide/how-to-format-numbers-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

al definir el tipo de dato `numeric(18,2)` el valor que se registre siempre tendrá máximo 2 decimales. Otra cosa es cómo se muestre ese valor, y ese se puede controlar de diferentes formas. El problema en el ejemplo que tienes es que estás convirtiendo un valor `numeric` (`@HUMEDAD NUMERIC (18,2)`) en un valor `varchar` (`@RESPUESTA VARCHAR (100)`)

```
SET @RESPUESTA = @HUMEDAD --AQUI VIENE EL CAMPO PARA SABER COMO BAJO DESDE ASP
SELECT @RESPUESTA AS RESPUESTA -- LO IMPRIMIMOS PARA VER COMO BAJO EL DATO
```

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede reproducir aunque en mi caso muestra :

```
DECLARE @DatoNumeric numeric(18,2), @DatoCadena varchar(100)      
SELECT @DatoNumeric = 1.5
SELECT @DatoCadena = @DatoNumeric
SELECT @DatoNumeric DatoNumeric, @DatoCadena DatoCadena

DatoNumeric     DatoCadena    
--------------  ------------- 
1.5             1.50
```

Como te digo, lo importante en BD es el valor que se "registra" y no tanto así el cómo se "muestra" dicho valor.